# Unable to compile for iOS 10 after Sierra Update

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, provisioning-profile

I have a certificate & provisioning profile generated this August. They are both valid (unexpired) in the Apple Developer Portal.

When I open my project, which targets 8.3, I get this error:

```
No certificate matching 'iPhone Developer: My Name (###ABC123)' for team 'Company.'
Select a different signing certificate for CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY, a team that matches your selected certificate, or switch to automatic provisioning.
```

- I can see the private key nested under my certificate in Keychain.
- In my Project settings, I click on my target and see my provisioning
  profile.
- Under Signing Certificate, I see None.

At first I saw an error for "This provisioning profile does not have Wireless Accessory Configuration", which I don't need. When I unselected & reselected the provisioning profile, this error went away.

Comment: When you select your target, then Build Settings, is your team selected under Development Team?

Comment: I too got some similar issue after I update to Sierra and with new Xcode 8.1, where I used the certificate and profile which was not expired. Then I checked Xcode preference and added the respective Apple IDs of the related account, Then it worked fine. And also if can try "Automatically manage signing" under Project->General.

Answer (score 7):

I've had many similar issues, where the developer portal displayed valid certificates/profiles, and Xcode refused to sign.

Finally found something that seems to do the trick every time I come across it:

• Open the `Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles` page on the online developer portal
• Go to the `Provisioning Profiles -> All` tab
• Select the profile you are trying to build for and click on `Edit`
• Select the certificate you have on your machine, and click 'Generate'
• Download the profile and drag in onto the Xcode icon in your dock
• Clean and rebuild your project

I don't know if this is the golden fix, or just happens to work in my situation... but worth giving this a shot for sure.

Answer (score 1):

I had a different compiling problem after upgrading; what helped me out a lot was someone pointing out that macOS El Capitan 10.11.1 and Sierra 10.12.1 put restrictions on root. I rebooted my computer in recovery mode (command+R), then from utilities -> terminal I typed

```
csrutil disable
```

then restarting the computer normally, I made sure that Xcode was installed properly using a download from the apple developer website and reinstalled programs relevant to me. Maybe this will help you?

Answer (score 1):

According to Apple's [Xcode 8.1 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Introduction.html) there are numerous signing issues noted. They are included below and have (not so detailed) recommended workarounds:
[image]

I've also included a [Xcode Signing Configuration Guide](https://pewpewthespells.com/blog/migrating_code_signing.html) that includes known issues and detailed explanations regarding the Xcode 8's Code Signing process and the differences from previous versions. Use the table of contents to visit the **Signing in Xcode 8** section, where you should find the steps to resolve the CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY error you're experiencing.

*** UPDATE ***

The [2016 WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/401/) on signing. It's pretty slow but it goes over the changes along with the fundamentals that have been made with the latest iOS updates and Xcode 8.

Comment: I believe they mean manually adjusting your .plist and bundle preferences in order to specify the signing identity(s) and/or provisioning profile associated with the project. Checkout the link I've added, directing you to the new WWDC video on signing.

Comment: Also, have you checked to see that your Xcode account is setup correctly with the signing identities required for the build? Xcode~>Preferences~>Accounts~>AppleID~>View Details...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Cordova, make sure you are using the latest version of the tools, or else follow the steps in this post: https://dpogue.ca/articles/cordova-xcode8.html. You will need to add a hook (JS file) and update your build.json file (or add one at the root if you don't have one). Don't forget to clean and rebuild your project.

If you also happen to use the Tools for Apache Cordova in Visual Studio, expect ERROR ITMS-90161 when uploading to the store. The only working workaround I'm aware of is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28113939/1010492) at Step 4:

> I then discovered the Xcode Project in
>   "...remote-builds/builds/"xxx-buildnmb"/cordovaApp/plattforms/iOS/"
>   and used Xcode to define the code signing identities in "Build
>   Settings" and the Team information in "General", created the archive
>   via Product-->Archive and submitted it in the Organizer - Archives

Comment: The most important part of the above is that you MUST USE THE XCODE GUI now!  It used to be you could build with Cordova and then just use the Application Loader to ship it out.  Now, you will get bad cert errors (on perfectly good certs) and waste hours/days of time until you use the XCode Archive option (requires build to be set to generic to activate that option) and uploader!

Answer (score 0):

How we handled this was to regenerate our certs and profiles:

1. When to Apple Developer Center

   - Deleted certs and profiles
   - Created two new certs - dev and distro
   - Created two profiles - dev and distro
2. Imported new certs into Keychain
3. Configured new profiles in Xcode

It worked easily.  I'm guessing I could have just done reimported the existing certs and profiles for steps 2 and 3 and not bothered recreating as in 1.